# How to Tesseract OCR for php without Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, ocr, tesseract

Hi can anyone help me to install Tesseract OCR for php without Composer. How can I use it on xampp server so that the code can be used to develop a web application. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you want to use composer?

Comment: Beside downloading source files and installing tesseractOCR itself you need to write custom autoloader that will find classes the same way as they're mapped in composer.json. Alternatively you can attack with brute force and include all the files before instantiating classes.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but still would have helped me out...  This is the code that I created to use the latest Tesseract without composer.  To those that are asking why, instead of creating a solution, why waste people's reading time when you don't understand?

```js
<?php
require_once "./tesseract-ocr/src/TesseractOCR.php";
require_once "./tesseract-ocr/src/Command.php";
require_once "./tesseract-ocr/src/FriendlyErrors.php";
require_once "./tesseract-ocr/src/Process.php";
require_once "./tesseract-ocr/src/TesseractOcrException.php";
require_once "./tesseract-ocr/src/TesseractNotFoundException.php";
require_once "./tesseract-ocr/src/ImageNotFoundException.php";
require_once "./tesseract-ocr/src/UnsuccessfulCommandException.php";

$filepath = "./images/processing";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator("$filepath");


use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;

foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
    $filename = $fileinfo->getFilename();

$fullfilepath = $filepath . "/" . $filename;
$ocr = new TesseractOCR("$filename");
try {
$content = $ocr->run();
}
catch (exception $e) {
 echo "$filename - No text, good image\n";
continue;
}

echo "$filename - There's Text!\n";
die();

}
}

?>
```

In this case, I'm using Tesseract just to detect if there's any text in an image at all (which for me is bad).